# How to set alarm when application has been idle for 30 seconds in android?

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarm

Hi I want to display alarm/alert when my application has been in idle mode. I tried by SCREEN_OFF and SCREEN_ON concept. But I couldn't get properly. Can anybody suggest me the best way of doing this? Thanks in advance.-